# Public class Main not working, is this code even possible or?

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I was doing some practicing with Java and I decided to try out some things so I asked my professor to give me some ideas to practice on and came up with this. When I went to compile it in Eclipse it wouldn't work, it has something to do with the public class Main but I have no clue what. Please tell me what I am doing wrong or if this would work at all.

[This is the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iamOK.jpg)

```
 public class Forecast 
{
    public int temperature;
    public int pressure;

}

public class Main
{
    public static void changeTheString(String weather)
    {
        weather = "sunny";
    }

    public static void changeTheArray(String[] rainyDays)
    {
        rainyDays[1] = "Sunday";
    }
    public static void changeTheObject(Forecast forecast)
    {
        forecast.temperature = 35;
    }
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String weather = "rainy";
        changeTheString(weather);
        String[] rainyDays;
        System.out.println("The rainy days were on " + rainyDays[0] + " and " + rainyDays[1]);

        String[] rainyDays = new String[] {"Monday", "Friday"};
        changeTheArray(rainyDays);
        System.out.println("The rainy days were on " + rainyDays[0] + " and " + rainyDays[1]);

        Forecast forecast = new Forecast();
        forecast.pressure = 700;
        forecast.temperature = 20;
        changeTheObject(forecast);
        System.out.println("The temperature is " + forecast.temperature + " Celsius");

    }

}
```

Comment: What error did you get ?

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: String[] rainyDays; is already declared and you need to just assign the values in coming lines in your code.

Comment: How did you execute it? What was the output?

Comment: Doesn't the error message explain exactly what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As aziz_aon pointed out you also need to either declare the class main in a separate file or make the class Forecast an internal class.
I'd suggest to move the Forecast class inside of the Main class
To do that you have to move it inside Main like you'd do it with a function.
(Sorry for formatting I'm on mobile)
The problem is you declare

```
String[] rainyDays;
```

then you try to assigen a new value like

```
String[] rainyDays = new String[] {"Monday", "Friday"};
```

but you already defined `rainyDays` as String[] so you can't do that again

change it to

```
rainyDays = new String[] {"Monday", "Friday"};
```

so your class looks like this:

```
 public class Forecast 
 {
     public int temperature;
     public int pressure;

}

public class Main
{
    public static void changeTheString(String weather)
    {
        weather = "sunny";
    }

    public static void changeTheArray(String[] rainyDays)
    {
    rainyDays[1] = "Sunday";
    }
    public static void changeTheObject(Forecast forecast)
    {
        forecast.temperature = 35;
    }
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
    String weather = "rainy";
    changeTheString(weather);
    String[] rainyDays;
    System.out.println("The rainy days were on " + rainyDays[0] + " and " + rainyDays[1]);

    rainyDays = new String[] {"Monday", "Friday"};
    changeTheArray(rainyDays);
    System.out.println("The rainy days were on " + rainyDays[0] + " and " + rainyDays[1]);

    Forecast forecast = new Forecast();
    forecast.pressure = 700;
    forecast.temperature = 20;
    changeTheObject(forecast);
    System.out.println("The temperature is " + forecast.temperature + " Celsius");

}

}
```

Comment: the error remains at line 8 public class Main where Main is red underlined. I will update the code with a screenshot of what I mean

Comment: Yeah you also will have to put forecast inside of main

Answer (score 1):

you have two options:

1- define the main class in its own file (separated from Forecast)

2- make the main class a nested class: your code will be like this:

```
 public class Forecast 
{
public int temperature;
public int pressure;

public class Main
{
    public static void changeTheString(String weather)
    {
        weather = "sunny";
    }

    public static void changeTheArray(String[] rainyDays)
    {
        rainyDays[1] = "Sunday";
    }
    public static void changeTheObject(Forecast forecast)
    {
        forecast.temperature = 35;
    }
}


public static void main (String[] args)
{
    String weather = "rainy";
    changeTheString(weather);
    String[] rainyDays;
    System.out.println("The rainy days were on " + rainyDays[0] + " and " + rainyDays[1]);

    String[] rainyDays = new String[] {"Monday", "Friday"};
    changeTheArray(rainyDays);
    System.out.println("The rainy days were on " + rainyDays[0] + " and " + rainyDays[1]);

    Forecast forecast = new Forecast();
    forecast.pressure = 700;
    forecast.temperature = 20;
    changeTheObject(forecast);
    System.out.println("The temperature is " + forecast.temperature + " Celsius");

}

}
```

Comment: Good answer totally missed that. Altough I'm not sure wether Java recognizes the public static void main inside of a nested class, so it might be better to nest Forecast in Main?